# Skipping parts of a file

Tags: java

I have written a code that gets me the values on where to split a file given the size. The problem is when the file length changes, I get incorrect values on where should I split the file.

This is the code:  (I'm not sure if this is the fastest way to determine where should I split the file.)

```
long parts = 5L;
long len = 123456L;
long partLen = len / parts;
long tmp = 1L;
for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
    tmp += partLen;
    long start = tmp - partLen;
    long end = tmp - 1L;
    System.out.printf("%d to %d\n", start, end);
}
```

This will output:

```
1 to 24691
24692 to 49382
49383 to 74073
74074 to 98764
98765 to 123455
```

These values are bytes. I'll be using these values to read a part of a file the write it.
Ex. Read the 1 byte to 24691 byte then write it to a file...

See that `123455` is not exactly `123456`. How can I add the remaining bytes?
What should I use to read the file, `RandomAccessFile`'s `seek()` + `read(byte[] b)`? or `BufferedInputStream`'s `read(buffer,offset,len)`?

Answer (score 0):

The difference you are seeing between the final byte and the length is the remainder. You are doing integer maths and len doesn't divide completely into parts. The result for the following all return the same partLen value

```
System.out.println(123455 / 5);
System.out.println(123456 / 5);
System.out.println(123457 / 5);
System.out.println(123458 / 5);
System.out.println(123459 / 5);
```

Produces the following output

```
24691
24691
24691
24691
24691
```

You need to take this into consideration when you calculate the partition size. If there is a remainder the partition size needs to be 1 larger. If there is no remainder then your current calculation is correct.

You can use either `RandomAccessFile` or `BufferedInputStream` depending on how you want to process the partitions. My personal preference would be to just open a `BufferedInputStream` once and switch output files when the partition length has been read. But there is nothing wrong with tackling each partition separately using `RandomAccessFile`.

Further to this:

1. Typically you would refer to bytes with a 0 based index (and indeed if you are using `RandomAccessFile.seek()` it will be expecting a seek position starting with 0 not 1) so initialise your `tmp` variable with 0.
2. I'm sure you are aware but the the last partition needs to be the min of end and len (len - 1 if you change to a 0 based index).